# Dynamic dropdown form breaks when enabling last JS function

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

I'm desiging a dynamic dropdown form that will help my customers choose the right product for them and was looking to test the function to output the final results. When I add the JS function to take the info from the last dropdown and use it to build the results list the whole script seems to break. My console in Chrome spits out `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` (pointing to the third to last line of the broken JS) although its nearly identical to my other functions except for some changed variables.

Basically, I use JS to pull info from dropdowns which sends that data using GET to a PHP script. The script then uses that data to query an SQL DB to dynamically build a list of options for the next dropdown. After the last dropdown of the form the JS would parse the PHP script to receive some data (a table eventually) and update a DIV with that data. This is where the script breaks. Adding that last JS function breaks the script while removing it keeps it working.

You can test the working script **[here](http://new.foxmeter.com/find.php)** and the broken script **[here.](http://new.foxmeter.com/findbroken.php)**

**Here's the working JS:**

```
        $(function(){
            $("#type").change(function() {
                var tval = document.getElementById('type').value;
                $("#source").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?type=" + tval));
            });
            $("#source").change(function() {
                sval = document.getElementById('source').value;
                $("#range").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?source=" + sval));
            });
            $("#range").change(function() {
                rval = document.getElementById('range').value;
                $("#setpoint").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?range=" + rval));
            });
            $("#setpoint").change(function() {
                stval = document.getElementById('setpoint').value;
                $("#dig_num").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?range=" + rval + "&setpoint=" + stval));
            });
          });
```

**And here's the broken JS:**

```
        $(function(){
            $("#type").change(function() {
                var tval = document.getElementById('type').value;
                $("#source").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?type=" + tval));
            });
            $("#source").change(function() {
                sval = document.getElementById('source').value;
                $("#range").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?source=" + sval));
            });
            $("#range").change(function() {
                rval = document.getElementById('range').value;
                $("#setpoint").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?range=" + rval));
            });
            $("#setpoint").change(function() {
                stval = document.getElementById('setpoint').value;
                $("#dig_num").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?range=" + rval + "&setpoint=" + stval));
            });
            $("#dig_num").change(function() {
                dnum = document.getElementById('dig_num').value;
                $("#findresults").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?range=" + rval + "&setpoint=" + stval "&dig_num=" + dnum));
            });
          });
```

I've looked it over a hundred times and can't figure out what's breaking the script.

If you'd like to see the PHP or anything just let me know.

Thanks in advance for ***any*** help.

Again, you can view the working script [here](http://new.foxmeter.com/find.php) and the broken script [here.](http://new.foxmeter.com/findbroken.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a "+" sign after stval.

```
$("#findresults").load(encodeURI("findbackend.php?range=" + rval + "&setpoint=" + stval + "&dig_num=" + dnum));
```

Comment: Oh, wow! Thanks a lot. What a simple mistake. I can't believe how long I missed that.